# Is there a way to use components imported in main.js all across the different Vue components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

For example, In main.js I imported Vue-Router and created a new vue router like that:

```
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: "history",
});


new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

Then In another component located in the components folder I'm trying to use:

```
router.push({ name: 'New page' });
```

But I'm getting

> 'router' is not defined  no-undef

Is there a way to only importing the component once?

Comment: You should use `this.$router.push({ name: 'New page' });`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim it depends on whether you are using `options` or the `composition` api right? In composition api  one must use `useRoute`. [read more](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html)

Comment: @Chin.Udara It looks like he's using vue 2 not vue 3

Comment: VueRouter is not a component - it is a Vue plugin. Once you install it on the root Vue instance, it is automagically available inside all your other components, under the name `this.$router`